# How to expose 2 port in one deployement and service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to expose 2 ports on one service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: etools
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: etools
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etools
        image: eregistry.azurecr.io/etools:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 3100
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: etools
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: etools
  ports:
  - port: 3100
  selector:
    app: etools
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Service` is very close, but in the [ports:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#serviceport-v1-core) array, the ports need to be named if there is more than one (they ideally would always have names), and the `selector:` is just once per `Service`, not per-port:

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: etools
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: other-port-something
    port: 3100
    targetPort: 3100
```

Be aware that while you will often see `port:` and `targetPort:` equal to the same number, they don't have to be. So your container could listen on 8080, because docker image says it will, but your `Service` could expose that to other members of your cluster as `port: 80` to be closer to what one would expect.

It's also possible to name the ports in your `PodSpec` with natural language names, and then point the `Service` at *that* value:

```
ports:
- name: http
  port: 80
  targetPort: http-in-my-pod
```

which I recommend because it decouples your `Service` from having to change just because the `containerPort` changed in your `PodSpec`, but at your discretion.

I'm a little surprised that `kubectl` didn't offer helpful feedback when you provided it that malformed yaml, but either way, I believe the snippet above is correct. As the docs specify, the names must be both unique within the Service, and also "DNS-compatible" names, so no underscores, spaces, crazy characters